# use cri-o to run pod and container when `cgroup_manager=systemd`

Tags: kubernetes, systemd, cgroups, cri-o

I successfully use cri-o to run pod and container, following the [guide](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/master/tutorials/setup.md) and [tutorial](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/master/tutorials/crictl.md), whose default `cgroup_manager` is `cgroupfs`.

when I tried to set `cgroup_manager = "systemd"` in `/etc/crio/crio.conf` and restart `crio` service.

then, I tried the same steps in [tutorial](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/master/tutorials/crictl.md)

```
POD_ID=$(sudo crictl runp test/testdata/sandbox_config.json)
```

got the error below:

```
FATA[0000] run pod sandbox failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = cri-o configured with systemd cgroup manager, but did not receive slice as parent: /Burstable/pod_123-456
```

the `sandbox_config.json` is same as [sandbox_config.json](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/master/test/testdata/sandbox_config.json)

How to use cri-o to start pod and container when `cgroup_manager=systemd`? Is there a sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you switch the cgroup manager to systemd in /etc/crio/crio.conf, you have to modify the pod yaml/json to give the cgroup_parent a slice instead.
So in your sandbox_config.json change

```
"linux": {
        "cgroup_parent": "/Burstable/pod_123-456",
```

to something like this

```
"linux": {
        "cgroup_parent": "podabc.slice",
```

Try re-creating your pod and it should start up fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a successful demo in [crictl.md](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/master/docs/crictl.md).

I think it may be the linux cgroup config in [sandbox_config.json](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/master/test/testdata/sandbox_config.json) above  is not suitable for systemd.

```
$ cat pod-config.json
{
    "metadata": {
        "name": "nginx-sandbox",
        "namespace": "default",
        "attempt": 1,
        "uid": "hdishd83djaidwnduwk28bcsb"
    },
    "log_directory": "/tmp",
    "linux": {
    }
}

$ cat container-config.json
{
  "metadata": {
      "name": "busybox"
  },
  "image":{
      "image": "busybox"
  },
  "command": [
      "top"
  ],
  "log_path":"busybox/0.log",
  "linux": {
  }
}
```

However, I still don't know how to config the `linux.*` in `sandbox_config.json` for systemd.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've had to do is set my cgroup-manager for crictl to systemd:
in `crictl.yaml`:

```
runtime-endpoint: unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock
cgroup-manager: systemd
```

As I understand it, you don't need to specify a cgroup in the pod config (you can, but it's not required). CRI-O and crictl just have to be asking for the same cgroup hierarchy